# No consigo que se muestre la lista de usuarios

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo una table User:

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('second_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('provincia')->nullable();
            $table->string('localidad')->nullable();
            $table->string('direccion')->nullable();
            $table->string('telefono');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('dni');
            $table->boolean('vehiculo')->default(false);
            $table->string('foto')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Quiero hacer una vista que permita ver a todos los usuarios. Para ello tengo este enlace en web.php:

```
Route::get('/inicio', 'UserController@index');
```

Tengo este código en UserController.php:

```
public function index(){
        $usuarios=User::latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('menus.inicio',compact($usuarios));
    }
```

Y tengo la siguiente vista:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <h1 class="text-center text-mute"> Usuarios </h1>
            @forelse($usuarios as $u)
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h2> {{ $u->name }} </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <h4>{{ $u->dni }}</h4>
                        <h4>{{ $u->telefono }}</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @empty
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <h1>No hay ningún usuario por el momento</h1>
                </div>
            @endforelse
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Pero me aparece el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si uso dd($usuarios) funciona, por lo que me gustaria saber que hago mal en la vista.

Comment: esta mal enviado el compact tiene que ser así `return view('menus.inicio',compact('usuarios'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si usas el método compact, no necesitas el signo de dólar

```
public function index(){
        $usuarios=User::latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('menus.inicio',compact('usuarios'));
    }
```

O bien puede ser con el método with, así

```
public function index(){
        $usuarios=User::latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('menus.inicio')->with('usuarios', $usuarios);
    }
```

> Ambos métodos de envio son validos, la única diferencia será que con
>   compact el nombre de la variable se manda como si fuera cadena de
>   texto y con el with primero declaras una especie de alias con el mismo
>   nombre de la variable y separado por una coma ahora si el nombre de la
>   variable que contiene tu data

Comment: Vale, ahora si funciona.

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en la forma en que envias la variable

> $usuarios

a la vista, solo quitale el simbolo de $ y encierrala entre comillas:

```
 public function index(){
        $usuarios=User::latest()->paginate(5);
//Quitarle el simbolo de dolar y encerrar entre comillas variable enviada en compact
        return view('menus.inicio',compact('usuarios'));
    }
```